# Is it possible to filter SolR results using Active Directory?

Tags: solr, filter, active-directory, ntlm

We use Solr to index an search through docs in our file system.

Currently, all users can access to all the docs. We'd like to change that, so that users can only access to some documents, according to their membership of a group in the Active Directory.

I've found that we can setup Apache to perform NTLM authentication, but I can't find anything about filtering results according to this authentication.

So, my question is : if we set up AD with groups like "SOLR_ACCESS_ALL", "SOLR_ACCESS_GROUP_1", "SOLR_ACCESS_GROUP_2","SOLR_ACCESS_GROUP_3", etc... can we set up SolR to filter results according to those memberships? We would also need to be able to give multiple access to some users (for example SOLR_ACCESS_GROUP_1 and SOLR_ACCESS_GROUP_3).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solr does not integrate with Active Directory out of the box. However, a different Apache project [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF%3F) integrates with Solr and - I believe - Active Directory among many other enterprise connections.

See, for example, [an article describing how to put these together](http://www.francelabs.com/blog/tutorial-on-authorizations-for-manifold-cf-and-solr/).